# .NET 4.5 Large String Stream and Dispose?

Tags: string, performance, wcf, out-of-memory

I have text files on disk, which are emitted to WCF callers as a string (actually POX content). Current WCF method code reads the whole file into memory as a string, returns the string. The method signature/Interface cannot change.

System popularity has grown and I suspect this is not going to be sustainable as some string results are 400k in size.

Can anyone recommend a way to tactically dispose (note I use lowercase "d" I am not necessarily asking about IDisposable) of Strings in .NET 4.5, or work through another way to serve a file as a string through WCF with as little memory usage as possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to setup compression on your responses. I found this article which enables compression on responses from WCF services using the GZip compression algorithm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx

Note: On the client side they theoretically should see in the message header that the content has been compressed with GZip, and automatically decompress the body. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the actual problem is that I am serving strings and need to clean them up internally. The problem is not what clients take, the clients think they are fine.

Comment: Are you keeping those strings in memory even after they've been served to a client?

Comment: I am not setting them explicitly to null, if that is what you are asking. That would not help anything, it would just set the reference to the string to 'nothing' but would not affect the string waiting to get internd.

Comment: I was wondering if you were caching the strings somewhere for quick access without having to go to a database of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Besides compression:

As far as I understand you have string type property in your response object and that's the main problem. A band aid solution is to call GC explicitly but according to MSDN

> "It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but
>   most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create
>   performance issues. "

So you'd better change your contract (if it's possible) and use streaming for transfering files.

Comment: Changing the contract is absolutely not possible. Multiple paying Java clients from large-scale enterprises touch this service daily. Changing the interface is not an option. Thanks.